Spring KafkaListener - strategy to endlessly retry up until successful handling
I need to endlessly retry any exception that might happen during consuming retry topic (even like deserialization errors, as in our case it might be due to temporary issues with schema registry) up until it successfully be handled, accepting the fact that specific partition will be blocked till the message will be processed. Messages are consumed in the following way:
@KafkaListener(topics = RETRY_EVENT_TOPIC, containerFactory = "customEventFactory")
public void handleRetryEvent(ConsumerRecord<String, CustomEvent> record) {
  ...
}

As I see, there are the following two possible approaches (I guess other approaches are present as well, e.g. previously it was an option to use SeekToCurrentErrorHandler to achieve similar stuff, but it's already deprecated):
Approach #1. Use endless backoff retry  for DefaultErrorHandler without specifying recoverer:
var errorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler(new ExponentialBackOff()); // ExponentialBackOff is endless if 'maxElapsedTime' not specified
errorHandler.setClassifications(Collections.singletonMap(Exception.class, true), true);
var factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
factory.setCommonErrorHandler(errorHandler);

Approach #2. Implement custom ConsumerRecordRecoverer that logs and throws exception, and use it for DefaultErrorHandler with fixed number of retries (as opposed to approach #1 with endless backoff retries):
public class ThrowingConsumerRecordRecoverer implements ConsumerRecordRecoverer {
  @Override
  public void accept(ConsumerRecord<?, ?> consumerRecord, Exception ex) {
    log.info("Exhausted recoverer");
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
  }
}


var errorHandler = new DefaultErrorHandler(new ThrowingConsumerRecordRecoverer(), new FixedBackOff(100, 5));
errorHandler.setClassifications(Collections.singletonMap(Exception.class, true), true);
var factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
factory.setCommonErrorHandler(errorHandler);

With approach #2, retry exhausted recoverer will be executed endlessly after each exhausted fixed retry, until successful execution. In my understanding, if ConsumerRecordRecoverer implementation does not throw exception, we commit offset and move forward, but in case of throwing exception - we stay on the same offset and retry starts again.
What should be considered by selecting one or another approach? Are they equivalent, or some concerns should be considered? Using approach #1, we endlessly retry in-memory (up until application is shut down), and the main concern is whether we should periodically give up with recoverer or it's unnecessary?
